# Why do images in my HTML emails resize nicely in firefox and IE, but not chrome?

Tags: html, css, email, google-chrome, firefox

In a daily digest news letter, I've often got several images. They all have the same constant width, but I need them to maintain their original aspect ratios. The code I used:

```
style="width: 300; height: auto;"
```

works fine in outlook native and Firefox and IE across all email clients, but in chrome the images maintain their original height and deform the entire email. How can I get the images to maintain their aspect ratios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do  not need `height:auto` just don't declare a height and it will keep the ratio automatically. Also, put `px` after your width value eg. `style="width:300px"`.

Comment: I tried that. No dice. The images maintain their default height in chrome.  

edit: I stand corrected. Not assigning height at all works fine.